# Create and place widget from subroutine

Tags: tcl

My form is a basic two label frames with one of them containing check boxes and the other is an image.  Below these two frames is a back and a start button.  The window is preset so that it cannot be altered but when the start button is pressed additional widgets appear on the screen.  However, I would like the widgets to only be created and placed on the screen after the checkbox has been selected and the start button has been clicked.  The start button then calls a function called "Balanced".  Within this code it creates the new widgets and places them on the window.  However, it returns an error: "bad window path name '.lblfrmProgress'"

```
#Set Dual UTA Window as top-level
set UTA .dual_uta
wm state . withdrawn
catch {destroy $UTA}
toplevel $UTA

#Window Properties
wm title  $UTA {Device: Dual UTA}
wm maxsize $UTA 522 231 ;#x-500, y-231
wm minsize $UTA 522 231 ;#x-500, y-231
```

The above is a section of the code that creates a window under the alias of UTA.  I thought that this window is the top-level window and as such could be referenced using $UTA.[pathname].

```
global UTA .dual_uta
#**************** DO NOT MODIFY - USER INTERFACE CODE *******************

    #Setup window with labels to show progress
    labelframe $UTA.lblfrmProgress  -text "Test Progress" -padx 1 -relief groove -height 145 -width 520
    label $UTA.lblUTASetup          -text "Dual UTA setup according to image"
    label $UTA.lblVQuadStart        -text "VQuad is initializing"
    label $UTA.lblVQTStart          -text "VQT is initializing"
    label $UTA.lblLMC               -text "Load 'Balanced' Master Configuration"
    label $UTA.lblTxRx1             -text "Side 1 Tx - Side 2 Rx"
    label $UTA.lblTxRx2             -text "Side 1 Rx - Side 2 Tx"
```

Am I referencing the window variable name incorrectly?  Do I need to pass the window variable via procedure call?  I just call the file by using 'source Balanced.tcl'

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When I try to pass values of variables to other files such as UTA to Balanced.tcl TCL returns the following error: "Wrong # args: should be 'source filename'"  How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `global` appears to be somewhat off. In particular, each argument to `global` is the name of a variable to map in; initialization should be done separately. Or you can both bring the variable in and (optionally) initialize it with the `variable` command:

```
proc whatever {} {
    variable UTA .dual_uta

    destroy $UTA;   # No error if $UTA doesn't exist
    toplevel $UTA
    wm title $UTA {Device: Dual UTA}
    labelframe $UTA.lblfrmProgress  -text "Test Progress" \
            -padx 1 -relief groove -height 145 -width 520
    # Etc.
}
```

It's usually considered better to use that form of `variable` only within the enclosing namespace (i.e., the global namespace, `::`, unless you say otherwise) and only use the single argument form inside a procedure.

```
variable UTA .dual_uta
proc whatever {} {
    variable UTA

    destroy $UTA
    toplevel $UTA
    wm title $UTA {Device: Dual UTA}
    labelframe $UTA.lblfrmProgress  -text "Test Progress" \
            -padx 1 -relief groove -height 145 -width 520
    # Etc.
}
```

Myself, I'd structure the procedure so that the “root name” of the window hierarchy to build was a parameter to the procedure, binding the name into any callbacks during creation:

```
proc whatever {UTA} {
    destroy $UTA
    toplevel $UTA
    wm title $UTA {Device: Dual UTA}
    labelframe $UTA.lblfrmProgress  -text "Test Progress" \
            -padx 1 -relief groove -height 145 -width 520
    # Etc.
    button $UTA.thingamijig -text "Fluffy Bunny" -command [list doTheCallback $UTA]
    # ...
}
```

I'd also be saving the names of widgets in variables for use in later `pack`/`grid` calls, so as to avoid having to write long widget paths quite so often. It's just slightly more mnemonic IMO, but certainly not necessary. (Binding the pathnames into callbacks *à la* the use of `list` above instead of using a global/namespace variable is better style though, and less problematic than writing callbacks with string substitutions.)

Comment: Could you correct any misconceptions and answer these questions?

1. The global command is used for variables that have already been established either through the variable command or the set command?
2. wm title $UTA {Device: Dual UTA} <-- Is this created outside of the global namespace?
3. To save widgets to variable names is that as simple as using the -variable flag?
4. Could you explain the "list" idea or point me to a website that explains it clearly.

Thanks for your suggestions.  I clearly have presented myself as a complete noob to TCL.

Comment: Disregard questions 2.  I know what that does. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Do you *create* the UTA variable in a proc? If so, you have to declare it global there too.

The `global` command takes one or more variable names, so `global UTA .dual_uta` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I do not create the UTA variable in a proc.  This variable is created at the beginning of the main file so I can create a new window.  Once all of the widgets have been made and placed onto the window, procedures are then called depending on how they are invoked.

When the "balanced" checkbox is checked and the start button is pressed, it sources this new file.  This new file is needed to add widgets that are specific to the test to the interface.  But to add it to the already visible interface it must reference it by looking at the variable $UTA.  I guess I'm looking to reference this window?